# Accessing void * struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, c99

I'm trying to find the bug in my implementation here, where I store a struct in another struct and cannot seem to access the value stored. I define two structs.

```
typedef struct {
    void * data;

} Element;

typedef struct {
    void **buckets;
} Storage;
```

In a separate function, I set `key` to be a pointer to a `char`. And pass it in to be stored in data.

```
void Function(const char *key, Storage *storageUnit)
{
    char keyValue[strlen(key) + 1];
    strcpy(keyValue, key); // To fix the discard qualifiers bit
    Element data = { keyValue }; // = new struct element;
    printf("Key %s\n", (char *)data.data); // This works.
    *(storageUnit->buckets) = &data;

    // Let's see if it got stored correctly?
    Element temp = *(Element *)(storageUnit->buckets);

    // This is gobbledygook
    printf("Stored correctly with data %s", (char *)(temp.data));
}
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: `char keyValue[strlen(key)];` should be `char keyValue[strlen(key)+1];` to hold the `'\0'` (but your array should be malloc'ed), but I don't think that's the main problem.

Comment: @jonsca good point. @Mitch it's passed in to the function. I've fixed my example up above.

Comment: Typedef'ing the structs isn't doing anything.  The code depends on their underlying type.  It does require the reader to remember what those types are, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
Element temp = *(Element *)(storageUnit->buckets);
```

to

```
Element *temp = (Element *)*(storageUnit->buckets);
```

and print statement from

```
printf("Stored correctly with data %s", (char *)(temp.data));
```

to

```
printf("Stored correctly with data %s", (char *)(temp->data));
```

**EDIT**
Not sure if this is a good way to do it, but I am pretty sure you can change

```
Element temp = *(Element *)(storageUnit->buckets);
```

to

```
Element temp = *(Element *)*(storageUnit->buckets);
```

Without changing the print statement and get the same behavior.

Comment: Nice! I'll have to spend some time deconstructing that, but it worked.

Comment: @Rio (storageUnit->buckets) is void ** , you can not cast that to (Element *) like you were doing. You need to reference first, cast it, and reference again.

Comment: @Rio, Take a look at the edit. I think you were trying to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you consolidated your posting a bit?  at one point it's storageUnit->buckets, then it's cm->buckets.  This makes me think the latter printing is actually outside the function, in which case it will blow up because Element data is a local variable that goes away once Function() returns.  You've added an automatic to your container.

I think you want
    Element data = new Element();
    data.data = keyValue;

Comment: Hi Christo, I made a mistake in trying to broaden my example. Each storageUnit->buckets is the same exact call.

Answer (score 0):

`char keyValue[strlen(key)];` is wrong since you use strcpy, you have to account for the nul terminator. make it `char keyValue[strlen(key) + 1];`. This is likely what's causing your issue in the last printf.

`*(storageUnit->buckets) = &data;` might be wrong too. `data` and `keyValue` are both allocated on the stack. When your `Function` returns, these objects are no longer valid, so storing that pointer in storageUnit->buckets[0] is useless. You should probably allocate the element and the key dynamically with e.g. malloc().

Comment: The first part I've fixed but it hasn't resolved the issue. If it's all within the same function, why at least would it not work?